# How to develop delete function in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am going to make a simple app and I am completely new to Android development. I want to develop a delete button to delete my data from the Realtime Database. This is my code:

```
holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Delete Confirmation");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                DatabaseReference updateRef = db.child("Homework");

                updateRef.child(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot nodeSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            nodeSnapshot.getRef().child(myItems.getName()).removeValue();

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        throw databaseError.toException();
                    }
                });

        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Code to dismiss the alert dialog
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
});
```

[image]

What I need to do to delete highlighted (In the image) Unique id direction. But this unique ID is not always the same. It changes every time when user creates a new one. All data inside unique id also change from time to time.

Comment: To delete a specific key, you need to know that key. Typically you'll know if because you've read that same data somewhere else in your app, and at that point also saved its key, and then passed that key along whenever you used that app. In your previous question I already showed you the three ways to delete data. Which one of those are you trying to apply here?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am planning to apply for the last one. I already used it for the edit function, and it worked. I am planning to make a reminder app I want to give access to users to delete and edit the records.

Comment: Deleting all child nodes is much simpler and requires just a single `updateRef.child(uid).removeValue();`

Comment: No, I want to delete them one by one. Is there any option?

Comment: Yes. I showed in my answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75422834/how-to-retrieve-push-valued-data-from-firebase-to-android) how to loop over all the results. In that loop you can then do `nodeSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();` (is that the part you're asking for?)

Comment: No. When I use this code, all the data in the table is deleted. I attached my code as an answer. Can you have a look?

Comment: Please don't post additional information as an answer, as that confuses the system. If you want to show a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful) you can click the `edit` link under your question to do so.

Comment: Since you're loading all data from `updateRef.child(uid)` and then delete each child, all child nodes will be deleted. That is exactly what the "Update all children" snippet in my answer to your previous question does. If you want to update/delete a subset or only one, you'll need to either know the keys if the node(s) to update, or use a query to determine those (which are the other two sections of my answer to your previous question).